# Why is this always evaluating to false?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a piece of code I made

```
abstract class WorkTypes
{
    const Portfolio = 0;
    const Study = 1;
}

function get_our_work ( $atts )
{

   // see https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

    $work_type = (strcmp($atts['workType'],'ports') === 0) ?  WorkTypes::Portfolio : WorkTypes::Study;

    include "page-content/our_work.php";
}
```

and for reason `$work_type` is always evaluating to be `WorkTypes::Study` even when I'm 100% sure that `$atts['workType']` is equal to `'ports'`. So I know that `(strcmp($atts['workType'],'ports') === 0)` is always evaluating to `false`. Why?

Comment: Maybe `$atts['workType']` has a leading or trailing space. Can you `var_dump($atts['workType']);`?

Comment: Your evaluation is correct. As Dave Chen pointed out, your `$atts['workType']` must not in fact be equal to ports, even when you think that it is.

Answer (score 0):

you're doing a boolean evaluation on a number?  I haven't done php in quite a while but I'm pretty sure you have to have something like:

$work_type = (strcmp($atts['workType'],'ports') <> 0) ? WorkTypes::Study :  WorkTypes::Portfolio;

Which reads, if your $atts['workType'] does not match 'ports' then WorkTypes::Study else it does match so use WorkTypes::Portfolio regardless of which comparison string is different.